# Android - Blank space remains after view is translated

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-animation

I am trying to animate my toolbar (used as ActionBar) to hide itself after scroll. I am using the following code to translate the toolbar up -

```
toolbar.animate().translationYBy(toolbar.getBottom()*(-1));
```

However, after the animation, the space occupied earlier by the toolbar earlier becomes white and remains there.

I want the content below the toolbar to move up and occupy the space left by the toolbar.

Comment: i also have same problem any solution

Answer (score 0):

The reason there’s white background after animating Toolbar is because of the way it is embedded in your layout.

There are a few ways of achieving this:

1. **Make Toolbar overlay the content**

   Use `FrameLayout` to hold both your toolbar and your Activity's content.

   ```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/picture"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:src="@drawable/jokic" />

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

   </FrameLayout>
   ```

[image: Full Screen Mode]

2. **Keep Toolbar above the content**

   As you animate the Toolbar you will have to animate the Activity's layout as well to take its place. Implementation details would depend on the content you're showing. For `RecyclerView` see [this blog](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling(part1)/)

[image: Full Screen Mode]

3. **Hide `ActionBar`**

   Simply request the action bar `getSupportActionBar().hide()` to hide and that will redraw the window.

[image]

Also, in case you're looking to do a Full-Screen [Immersive](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) Activity, this should cover that.